# iMac 27“ Mid 2011 - Can‘t reinstall macOS

Tags: hard-drive, imac, disk-utility, partition

I‘m trying to reinstall macOS Sierra on my Mid 2011 iMac. I have a single 1 TB HDD and single partition called „OS X Base System“ that takes up 999.35 GB‘s. When I try to partition the Base Volume I get the following error

```
This volume has 1.56 GB used space. You can not remove the first volume on the disk. This volume can not be split because the resulting
volumes would be too small.
```

Also when just try to reinstall the OS the disk is greyed out and when hovering on it, it says

`This disk is locked.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've somehow installed a MacOS installer disk onto your internal drive. Then you're booting up to that, and trying to install the OS over itself, or trying to partition the volume of the running system.

Boot to Recovery (Command R at restart) and wipe the disk from there. Then install the OS.

Comment: When I start or restart the iMac, it always boots into Recovery Mode (Cmd + R). I get the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: In which case you've wiped the Recovery Partition, and you'll need to use Internet Recovery - Command Alt R.

Comment: I've tried that, started in Recovery Mode connected to WiFi, also additionally connected the Mac via Ethernet, the globe shows up and it takes roughly 10 minutes after that it reboots and then the Apple logo is there and nothing happens. I've let the Mac run throughout the night and it was still stuck there.

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac, or a spare external drive? Next step is to try installing from another Mac using Target Mode to connect this iMac as an external disk. Or just try to install MacOS onto an external volume, then see if you can boot up there and fix the internal.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to another Mac at the moment. I'm currently in the process of creating a boot drive through my windows machine using TransMac. I hope this works.

Comment: Does the internal drive boot up itself? You may be able to install MacOS on an external from there.

Comment: Downloaded the an official .dmg-file from Apple‘s Website and formatted it with TransMac and now the iMac doesn‘t recognize the USB when holding the Option key but when I go into Disk Utility it shows up as the installer.

Comment: Also the internal drive always boots up but like mentioned above the USB isn‘t recognized and the drive can‘t be formatted.

Comment: For some reason it‘s now in the OS X Lion Recovery mode and I‘ve managed to separate the two volumes now but when I want to install OS X Lion I get „Can‘t download the additional components need to install Mac OS X“ as an error. @benwiggy